# How to change the <!DOCTYPE> declaration from version HTML4.01 to HTML 5 in IntelliJ

Tags: html, intellij-idea, javadoc

When generating JavaDoc documentation in IntelliJ 2018.3.3 (Community Edition) I get this information

> Constructing Javadoc information...
>
> javadoc: warning - You have not specified the version of HTML to use.
> The default is currently HTML 4.01, but this will change to HTML5
> in a future release. To suppress this warning, please specify the
> version of HTML used in your documentation comments and to be
> generated by this doclet, using the -html4 or -html5 options.

At the moment the first statement of all generated HTML-files is:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"  "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
```

Therefore I changed the **default HTML language level** from HTML 4 to HTML 5 at

> Project Settings - Languages & Frameworks - Schemas and DTDs - Default XML Schemas

In addition I looked at the project settings at

> Editor - File and Code Templates - Default Scheme

There are templates for HTML and HTML4, but not for HTML5.
I wonder about how to change to the right version of HTML as required.
Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the message you've quoted says, you can specify the version of the HTML generated by JavaDoc by specifying the -html5 option. In IntelliJ IDEA, this option can be specified under "Other command line arguments:" in the Tools | Generate JavaDoc... dialog.

None of the other options you've tried to change have any impact on JavaDoc generation.